# Ruby on Rails: I'm trying to recursively generate a hash, but I get {...} where there is supposed to be another depth of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion, hash

This is what I've been getting:

```
{:user=>{:employees=>{...}, :login=>"dernalia", :id=>1, :role=>2}}
```

What is generating the hash:

```
  def management_tree(args = {})
    args = {:users => [], :result => {}}.merge(args) #defaults
    result = args[:result]

    if not args[:users].include? self.login #prevent duplicates
      result.merge!({:user => {:id => self.id, 
                              :login => self.login,
                              :role => self.role,
                              :employees => employee_tree(args[:users] + [self.login], args[:result])
                              }
                    })      

    end
    logger.info result.inspect
    return result
  end

  def employee_tree(users, result)
    if self.employees.length > 0
       self.employees.each {|emp| (emp.management_tree({:users => users, :result => result})) }
    end
    return result
  end
```

Now... it's supposed to return something like this:

```
{:user=>{:login=>"me", :id=>1, :role=>2, 
        :employees=>{
             :user => {:login => "2", ...},
             :user => {:login => "3",
                   :employees => {...}
         }

}}
```

Some console output:

```
% bundle exec script/console
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.8)
>> require "awesome_print"
=> []
>> ap User.find(1).management_tree[:employees]
nil
=> nil
>> ap User.find(1).management_tree
{
    :user => {
        :employees => {...},
             :role => 2,
            :login => "me",
               :id => 1
    }
}
=> {:user=>{:employees=>{...}, :role=>2, :login=>"me", :id=>1}}
>>
```

now... it says that employees is nil... but it shouldn't be... it should have 3 hashes ... =\

but also, what does {...} mean? it seams terribly ambiguous

Comment: How are you viewing the resulting hash?  The string you show just looks to me like the deeper level hash has been "folded"; i.e. not displayed just for readability purposes.  Note that hash ordering isn't dependable, so the fact that the employees hash is before or after the login shouldn't matter.

Comment: <%= @user.management_tree.inspect%><br><br>
but, I'm viewing it with the logger.info line, as well

Comment: You should probably do some tests to make sure you don't actually have what you're looking for there.  It may just be displaying as ... but not actually be that.

Comment: You don't want `User.find(1).management_tree[:employees]`, you want `User.find(1).management_tree[:user][:employees]`.

Comment: doh. that was silly. but it returns the samething as just .management_tree().  So there is something wrong with my recursion... maybe.... is there a way to view a hash so many levels deep?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3537/discussion-between-jacobm-and-thelindyhop)

Comment: Your best bet is to run this in script/console and get the results into a variable.  Then you can get the various levels of hashes out and inspect them each.

Comment: well... I can add [:user][:employees] as many times as I want, and I keep getting the same result =\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby is clever about recursive structures and will use `"..."` instead of looping indefinitely.

For example:

```
a = [1, 2]
a << a # a is now recursive, since it contains itself
a.to_s # => [1, 2, [...]]
a[2][2][2][2][2][2][2] == a # => true
```

In your case, the `{...}` refers to any of the hashes already in the process of being outputed.

Maybe what you meant to do was to insert a copy of a hash? In the simple array example:

```
a = [1, 2]
a << a.dup # a is not recursive
a.to_s # => [1, 2, [1, 2]]
```

Comment: thanks! yeah, I keep forgetting ruby doesn't make copies of everything everywhere like java does